# React redux cross origin error / typerror not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

Trying to build the basic todo app from [the redux guide](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html)

I have all the files seen existing in the guide's same folder structure. But I also have other files, generating other bundles for use on other routes from a node server.

Up until I brought in redux, the app was working fine.

Whenever I try to dispatch an action to the redux store, I get these two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _actions.addTodo) is not a function
Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.
```

From looking around online it seems like it could be a few things

A) I am trying to create an app with multiple chunks: (I tried adding the crossOriginLoading attr)

```
entry: {
    service: APP_DIR + '/service-side/service.index.jsx',
    admin: APP_DIR + '/admin-side/Admin.jsx',
    todo: APP_DIR + '/todo.index.jsx'
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    crossOriginLoading: "anonymous"
```

B) Set the included script to crossorigin setting:

```
<script crossorigin type="text/javascript" src="./dist/todo.bundle.js"></script>
```

C) Using a CDN? Not using any CDNs

D) Devtool set to

```
devtool: {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'
}
```

I use webpack to make a bundle, and then serve that bundle up on an HTML page. The app doesn't even make any requests, so I am confused why a CORS problem would even come up...

Anybody know anything else I can try to debug this?

Edit: a bunch of React code:

INDEX

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from 'redux'

import todoApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(todoApp)

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

APP

```
import React from 'react'
import Footer from './Footer'
import AddTodo from '../containers/AddTodo'
import VisibleTodoList from '../containers/VisibleTodoList'

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <AddTodo />
        <VisibleTodoList />
        <Footer />
    </div>
)

export default App
```

ADDTODO

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
          input.value = ''
        }}
      >
        <input
          ref={node => {
            input = node
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

actions/index.js

```
let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = text => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  }
}

export const setVisibilityFilter = filter => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
    filter
  }
}

export const toggleTodo = id => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you dispatching the action, might be an error there, in you action creators or container

Comment: Hey thanks Shubham, I added the path down to the action. I'm pretty sure wrapping the AddTodo container in the Provider gives it access to dispatch?

Comment: Things look good in the above code, can you make sure that addTodo is exported in the actions file and that the path is correct

Comment: Hi there ,  try giving full path in import. import { addTodo } from '../actions/index'

Comment: addTodo is being exported, and that's what's used in the container I guess?

Comment: oh my! Wow, yes that was the issue DX Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving full path in import.

```
 import { addTodo } from '../actions/index'
```

- Help :)